# System.Console.WriteLine not displaying output in unit tests

Tags: c#

I'm putting some console output in my unit tests while I use them to debug my code, but I'm not seeing the output written anywhere - because there is no console window?

How should I output from my unit test code so it will show in the debug output window(s)?

Comment: IO is a side effect and really has no place in unit tests. Ideally your unit tests are simple enough to not really need much debugging that can't be done by visual inspection, but you can always use the debugger + breakpoints for this.

Comment: Yeah as I said I'm really using the unit tests to debug my code without writing a standalone test-app, it's not really intended this will be final code

Comment: There is no console on unit test, use Debug.Write()

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Trace.WriteLine` instead.  Output will be displayed in the output window, regardless whether you're having a Debug or Release build.

Actually, if you're using xUnit as a test-library, you should also take a look at the `ITestOutputHelper` : https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output

Answer (score 1):

use `Debug.Write()` , Output will be displayed in the output window.